# Broken package click on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: apt, 16.10, python3, click-packages

When I run /usr/bin/click, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 37, in <module>
    import click
ImportError: No module named 'click'
```

I tried to reinstall package click, but I got the same error during installation:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/14,7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 255715 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../click_0.4.45.1+16.10.20160916-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking click (0.4.45.1+16.10.20160916-0ubuntu1) over (0.4.45.1+16.10.20160916-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Setting up click (0.4.45.1+16.10.20160916-0ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 37, in <module>
    import click
ImportError: No module named 'click'
dpkg: error processing package click (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.7-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 click
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have already removed another package `click`, which comes from pip3, but it didn't help. It seems that either required files (I believe that their source is [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/click/vivid/files/head:/click/)) are absent on the system or python cannot find it.

So the questions are: where python package `click` should be located, and how can I fix the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution! In my case python module `click` came from aptitude package `python3-click-package`. However, it has been overwritten by another module [`click`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/click). After I removed the latter module, `python3-click-package` was left broken, so I simply reinstalled it, so that `click` works now:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-click-package
```

Comment: Thanks worked for me. Just as a side note, you can remove click with `pip uninstall click`.

Comment: While I was able to remove click using pip, I still encountered errors relating to the package and had to use `sudo apt remove click`